# How to keep the left side of my model Mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier

I have modeled a low poly human figure with the mirror modifier. I then rigged it and when I move the right side the left side is mirroring the right side. when i turn off the mirror modifier the left side of the model disappears. Im sure its an easy fix im just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You'll need to apply the modifier before you can move the two sides individually.

Comment: You need to put the Armature modifier under the Mirror, but as John Eason says it may be more convenient to apply the Mirror